# Where is the middleware variable set?

Tags: mean.io

I have found this code:

```
Meanio.prototype.chainware = {

  add: function(event, weight, func) {
    middleware[event].splice(weight, 0, {
      weight: weight,
      func: func
    });
    middleware[event].join();
    middleware[event].sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a.weight < b.weight) {
        a.next = b.func;
      } else {
        b.next = a.func;
      }
      return (a.weight - b.weight);
    });
  },
```

but nowhere in the sourcecode can I find where middleware is defined.

And when I do a[1] = 3 just as a test, I get an error. So, I have determined that middleware must be defined somewhere, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Does anyone happen to know where this is or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found it in a glaringly obvious location, as so often is the case:

```
var events = new EventEmitter(),
  middleware = {
    before: {},
    after: {}
  };
```

For some reason I was reading this as middleware being part of the EventEmitter() object.